# How to convert a list of dictionary into dict?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of dict and want to convert into a dict because I want to access the value based on the key? Example:

```
my_lst = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}]
# desired output
my_dict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
print(my_dict.get('c')) # 3
```

Comment: What's wrong with indexing? `print(my_list[0].get('c'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a list with a single item - your dictionary - just *get it by index*:

```
my_dict = my_lst[0]
print(my_dict.get('c'))
```